# A app use redis multiple databases can improve performance?

Tags: database, redis

My app now stores all keys in one redis db. now I want to segment keys so with multiple DBs I can can get performance improvement. Is this possible? Although Redis is only one thread, with data in multiple databases, I hope data volume in one database data will be reduced and search will be quick.

Comment: Depends on what kind of searches you do. If you structure your data properly, most accesses are O(1) and do not depend on dataset size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having multiple Redis will help you much and I don't think it search will be faster with use of multiple DBs. However redis pipelining can help you

> Redis supports /topics/pipelining, so it is possible to send multiple
>   commands at once, a feature often exploited by real world
>   applications. Redis pipelining is able to dramatically improve the
>   number of operations per second a server is able do deliver.
>   -redis.io-

Check: http://redis.io/topics/pipelining